# ExternalSensor Airflow with multiple dependencies

Tags: python, airflow

I try to use external sensor for checking multiple tasks but when I ran it in for loop the time show only the last value of the list. I don't know why does it get the last value. This my code

```
TASK_DEPENDENCIES = [
    {
        "name": "dag_1",
        "external_dag_id": "dag_1",
        "day_offset": 0,
        "hour": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "dag_2",
        "external_dag_id": "dag_2",
        "day_offset": 1,
        "hour": 7
    }
]

dependency_check_tasks = []

for task in TASK_DEPENDENCIES:
        dependency_check_tasks.append(
            ExternalTaskSensor(
                task_id=f"check_external_sensor_{task['name']}_task_success",
                external_dag_id=task['external_dag_id'],
                external_task_id=task.get('external_task_id',None),
                allowed_states=["success"],
                check_existence=True,
                mode="reschedule",
                poke_interval=20,  # 60 * 5
                timeout=60 * 60 * 2,
                retries=1,
                execution_date_fn=lambda dt: dt.replace(hour=task['hour']) + timedelta(days=task['day_offset'])
            )
        )
```

**example airflow execution_date is 2023-04-30T11:00:00+00.00**

the result that i got when running the code

```
INFO - Poking for dag_1.None on 2023-05-01T07:00:00+00:00 ...

INFO - Poking for dag_2.None on 2023-05-01T07:00:00+00:00 ...
```

The correct results are

```
INFO - Poking for dag_1.None on 2023-04-30T10:00:00+00:00 ...

INFO - Poking for dag_2.None on 2023-05-01T07:00:00+00:00 ...
```